# How to take derivative of a interpolated function inside the module

Tags: interpolation, scoping, downvalues

When handling derivatives of a interpolated function, I often use the following function

```
makeDeriv[f_InterpolatingFunction] = D[ f[x], x]
```

Then,  I can define the derivative of `f`, by defining a downvalue as

```
interpolated = Range[5]^2 // Interpolation;
deriv[x_] = makeDeriv[interpolated]; (* To find a derivative once and then to use it later. *) 
deriv[3] (* Find a numerical value now*)
```

The purpose of this construct is to find the derivative once, and then use it later whenever I want to take derivatives.
(As a side question: will that be a better way than computing it from `f` every time for each numerical argument I will be interested?)

But then, if I want to define a similar function inside the `Module`, it does not seem to work, i.e.,

```
Module[ { qq},
   qq[x_] = makeDeriv[interpolated];
   qq[2]
](*It works!!*)
```

However,

```
Module[ { qq, int = interpolated},
    qq[x_] = makeDeriv[int];
    qq[2]
 ](*It does not work!!*)
```

Please explain why it happens and how to circumvent this problem.

(As another side question, let me know how to define the derivative of interpolation function properly.)

Comment: Not enough time now to test this, but have you tried: `makeDeriv[f_InterpolatingFunction] := D[ f[x], x]` ,`deriv[x_] := makeDeriv[interpolated]`, and `qq[x_] := makeDeriv[interpolated]`?  The  ":" might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's bad practice to have your functions depend on global symbols like `x` buried in their definitions, for *Mathematica* under certain conditions rewrites function parameters as `x$_` to avoid clashing with the global symbol.  Use `Trace` on the OP's examples to see that in the second one, `x_` is rewritten as `x$_.  See the tutorial [Variables in Pure Functions and Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html) and these questions for further discussion:

- [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia)
- [How to make a function that evaluates an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13757/how-to-make-a-function-that-evaluates-an-expression)
- [Name rewriting for Function fails in closure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95471/name-rewriting-for-function-fails-in-closure).

There are others, too, I'm sure.

One workaround is to use `Derivative` directly:

```
Module[{qq, int = interpolated},
 qq = Derivative[1][int];
 qq[2]]
(*  4   *)
```

Another way:

```
Module[{qq, int = interpolated, x},
 qq[x_] = D[int[x], x];
 qq[2]]
```

Or include all symbols as function parameters:

```
Clear[makeDeriv];
makeDeriv[f_InterpolatingFunction, x_] := D[f[x], x];
Module[{qq, int = interpolated, x},
 qq[x_] = makeDeriv[int, x];
 qq[2]]
```

And so forth, but I think the first two are simplest.

Comment: One more reference with an answer I started which Leonid *greatly* extended: [(20766)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks.  Added.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to your code, you can redefine your derivative taking function a little bit:

```
makeDeriv[f_InterpolatingFunction[x_]] := D[f[x],x]
```

and call it accordingly in your `Module` environment

```
int = Interpolation[Range[5]^2];

Module[{modint = int, dint},
  dint[x_] = makeDeriv[modint[x]];
  dint[1.2]
] (* Out[1] = 2.4 *)
```

I suppose that the unspecified variable `x` in your definition of the `makeDeriv` function leads to the problem, although I am not entirely sure why this only happens in your last example. Anyway, the above definition should be safe.

Two alternatives for taking the derivatives:

```
D[int[x],x] /. x -> 1.2 (* Out[2] = 2.4 *)

Derivative[1][int][1.2] (* Out[3] = 2.4 *)
```

so there should be no need to come up with your own function in the first place