# Pure function within another function

Tags: scoping, pure-function, variable

I am writing a function along the lines of the following:

```
func[basis_,coordinates_,vars_]:=Table[Function[vars,monomial]@@@coordinates,{monomial,basis}]
```

The idea would be to call somethings like

```
func[{x,x*y},{{0,1},{1,2}},{x,y}]
```

and then receive as output

```
{{0,1},{0,2}}
```

However, `vars` as it appears on the right hand side is not the same `vars` as appears on the left hand side because of how `Function` works. (Mathematica warns of this by highlighting `vars` in red with the message "A variable name has been used twice in a nested scoping construct, in a way that is likely to be an error.")

First, how can I get around the name scope problem that Mathematica warns about? Then, is this even a appropriate way to go about what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Alternative to pure functions: `{x, x*y} /. Thread[{x, y} -> Transpose@{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}]` or `basis /. Thread[vars -> Transpose@coordinates]` (provided `basis` consists of poly/mo-nomials).

Comment: Related tutorial: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html. Related Q&A: [(13757)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13757), [(20766)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766), [(95471)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95471)

Comment: Thanks for the references!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[func1]
func1[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := 
 Table[(Function @@ {vars, monomial}) @@@ coordinates, {monomial, basis}]

func1[{x, x*y}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {x, y}]
```

> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}

or

```
ClearAll[func2]
func2[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := 
 Table[(Function[x, y] /. {x -> vars, y -> monomial}) @@@ coordinates, {monomial, basis}]

func2[{x, x*y}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {x, y}]
```

> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering, this seems to work:

```
func[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := 
  Table[With[{monomial = monomial},
    Function[Evaluate@vars, monomial] @@@ coordinates], {monomial, 
    basis}]
```

<strike>The `Evaluate@vars` prevents `Function` from treating `vars` as a symbol (which would result in a one-parameter `Function`).  Instead, it passes `{x,y}`, as you need.</strike>  <sub>See [comments on this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149849/pure-function-within-another-function/149873?noredirect=1#comment401943_149873) for discussion of why this is wrong.</sub>

I confess I don't full understand why we need the `With` statement.  My current level of understanding is that there's some funny business going on between the `Table` variable's scoping and the `Function`'s `HoldAll` attribute, so we need `With` to force the `Function` to properly deal with `monomial` as a table variable.  See other questions, e.g. [(Function in Table)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121) or perhaps [(How can I create a List of Functions)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25389/11035), for more informed discussion.

Comment: The need for the `With` statement is curious... it looks like it can be replaced however by evaluating `monomial` within `Function`, like this: `func[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := 
 Table[Function[Evaluate@vars, Evaluate@monomial] @@@ 
   coordinates, {monomial, basis}]`. Why it needs to be evaluated, I am still not sure though.

Comment: Also it seems like the `Module[{mon},...]` is not needed... how come you have that in the function definition?

Comment: @Grayscale Ah, good catch on the `Module[{mon},...]` -- it's an unwelcome relic of a bygone version of the code.  I'll get rid of it presently.

Comment: @Grayscale Yes, I actually realized that after I read klgr's answer -- a nice trick I learned on this site is to use `f@@{a,b}` rather than `f[Evaluate@a, Evaluate@b]`.  The point of the `With[{monomial=monomial},...` statement is to force the variable to evaluate anyway.

Comment: You need `Evaluate@vars` for a different reason.  The symbol `vars` won't be treated as an unevaluated symbol, since the evaluation mechanism injects its value (e.g. `{x, y}`) into `Function[..]` before the `HoldAll` attribute applies. What you need it for is to prevent `{x, y}` from being renamed `{x$, y$}` when `monomial` is injected into `Function`.  *Mathematica* assumes the symbols in `monomial` are meant to be independent symbols. To get around this, you have to do something like the variants found in your, @kglr's and my answers.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the comment -- what I said is certainly incorrect.  But do `{x,y}` get renamed to `{$x,$y}`?  It seems like `func[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := Table[Function[vars, Evaluate@monomial] @@@ coordinates, {monomial, basis}]` actually works -- the front end just highlights `vars` in red.  One can also remove the `@@@coordinates` and check the `FullForm` of the returned function to see they aren't renamed.

Comment: If you `Trace[]` the command, it shows the renaming: `func[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := Table[With[{monomial = monomial}, Function[vars, monomial] @@@ coordinates], {monomial, basis}]; func[{x, x*y}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {x, y}] // Trace`.  (Note that `monomial` is also renamed, but that is irrelevant to the problem, I think.) The red `vars` is just a warning of a potential scoping conflict, which we have in this case but not in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, I see.  The renaming seems to only occur inside a `With`/`Module` construct, not when `Function` stands alone.  Thanks for clarifying.  `func[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := Table[With[{monomial = monomial}, Function[vars, monomial] ], {monomial, basis}]; func[{x, x*y}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {x, y}]` also makes the renaming clear.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
func[basis_, coordinates_, vars_] := Function[vars, #] @@@ coordinates & /@ basis;

func[{x, x*y}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {x, y}]
(*  {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}  *)
```