# Lambda calculus reduction in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, symbolic

Are there any built-in functions for reducing lambda terms in *Mathematica*? If not, how might one do it? I've heard of `Function`, which is good for $\beta$-reduction, but it [doesn't seem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95471/name-rewriting-for-function-fails-in-closure) to properly handle $\alpha$-conversion. Regarding $\eta$-reduction, the best I could find was this snippet from *A New Kind of Science* ([ref](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/notes-11-12--combinators/)):
`rm[h_, v_] /; FreeQ[h, v] = k[h]`

Specifically, what I need is the following:

- A function `reduce[term_]` which returns `term` after one step of reduction. It will do one of the following:

  - $\alpha$-conversion (if necessary) followed by $\beta$-reduction
  - $\eta$-reduction
- Abstraction and application are represented as functions, each taking two arguments:

  - Abstraction: $\lambda x.m$ is `lam[x_, m_]`
  - Application: $n\ m$ is `app[n_, m_]`
- Other details

  - If no reduction is possible, `reduce` returns `term` unchanged
  - The reduction strategy is [normal order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction_strategies)
  - For $\alpha$-conversion, you can choose any method to change the names of variables, such as appending a character (`x` → `x´`), incrementing a number (`x1` → `x2`), or changing the name altogether (`x` → `a`)

Examples of use:

$\beta$-reduction

```
reduce @ app[lam[x, lam[y, x]], a]
```

> ```
> lam[y, a]
> ```

$\alpha$-conversion, $\beta$-reduction

```
reduce @ app[lam[x, lam[y, x]], y]
```

> ```
> lam[y´, y]
> ```

More complex $\alpha$-conversion

```
reduce @ lam[y´, app[lam[x, lam[y, x]], app[y´, y]]]
```

> ```
> lam[y´, lam[y´´, app[y´, y]]]  (* y became y´´ to avoid clashing with the first y´ *)
> ```

Normal order

```
reduce @ lam[x, app[lam[y, y], x]]
```

> ```
> lam[y, y]  (* eta-reduction was done before beta-reduction *)
> ```

Lambda term in normal form

```
reduce @ app[a, b]
```

> ```
> app[a, b]  (* Nothing can be reduced, so the term is left unchanged *)
> ```

If anything is difficult to understand, you're very welcome to ask about it.

Comment: In order to get a good answer, you are going to have to be much clearer about what kinds of functions you are looking for. Can you give examples of what you expect such a function to do?

Comment: @bills I have now clarified the specific requirements.

Comment: Find a copy of Gray's "Mastering Mathematica" - IIRC (away from that home so I can't check book), it has an implementation of the LC.

Comment: @ciao Thank you, I'll be sure to look into that.